# HashSet.IntersectWIth using a custom IEqualityComparer produces wrong results in Mono

Tags: c#, mono, intersection, hashset, iequalitycomparer

I'm having in issue where a certain piece of code is running as expected in .NET 4.0 but not in Mono 2.6 (in Unity3D). Please have a look:

```
    void Test()
    {
        Func<string, MemberInfo> get = name => typeof(HSTest).GetField(name, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        var m1 = new TestMember { MemberInfo = get("x") };
        var m2 = new TestMember { MemberInfo = get("y") };
        var m3 = new TestMember { MemberInfo = get("x") };
        var m4 = new TestMember { MemberInfo = get("x") };
        var m5 = new TestMember { MemberInfo = get("a") };
        var m6 = new TestMember { MemberInfo = get("b") };
        var l1 = new List<TestMember> { m1, m2, m3 };
        var l2 = new List<TestMember> { m4, m5, m6 };
        var ll = new List<List<TestMember>> { l1, l2 };
        var comparer = new TestMemberComparer();
        var res = IntersectAll(ll, comparer);
        res.Foreach(Debug.Log); // In .NET this prints "x" in Mono it doesn't print anything
    }

    // Credits to Jon Skeet
    public static List<T> IntersectAll<T>(List<List<T>> lists, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer)
    {
        HashSet<T> hashSet = null;
        foreach (var list in lists)
        {
            if (hashSet == null)
            {
                hashSet = new HashSet<T>(list, comparer);
            }
            else
            {
                hashSet.IntersectWith(list);
            }
        }
        return hashSet == null ? new List<T>() : hashSet.ToList();
    }
}

public class TestMember
{
    public MemberInfo MemberInfo { get; set; }
}

public class TestMemberComparer : IEqualityComparer<TestMember>
{
    public bool Equals(TestMember x, TestMember y)
    {
        return x.MemberInfo.Equals(y.MemberInfo);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(TestMember obj)
    {
        return obj.MemberInfo.GetHashCode();
    }
}

public class HSTest
{
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public int z;
    public int a;
    public int b;
    public int c;
}
```

In .NET I'm getting 'x' as the result of the intersection, in Mono I'm not getting anything back.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

Using the name instead of the actual MemberInfo object doesn't help either

```
public class TestMemberComparer : IEqualityComparer<TestMember>
{
    public bool Equals(TestMember x, TestMember y)
    {
        return x.MemberInfo.Name.Equals(y.MemberInfo.Name);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(TestMember obj)
    {
        return obj.MemberInfo.Name.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

I should also mention that using a different way to intersect doesn't cause any issues (Both when using `MemberInfo` and `MemberInfo.Name` in the `GetHashCode` and `Equals`):

```
var res = ll.Aggregate((p, n) => p.Intersect(n, comparer).ToList());
```

EDIT: Here's a test with some logs inside the comparer

```
    void Test()
    {
        // ... define everything like in previous code
        var comparer = new TestMemberComparer();
        var hs = new HashSet<TestMember>(l1, comparer);
        hs.IntersectWith(l2);
        hs.ToList().Foreach(Debug.Log);
    }

public class TestMemberComparer : IEqualityComparer<TestMember>
{
    public bool Equals(TestMember left, TestMember right)
    {
        bool result = left.MemberInfo.Name.Equals(right.MemberInfo.Name);
        Debug.Log("Comparing `" + left.MemberInfo.Name + "` with `" + right.MemberInfo.Name + "` Result: " + result);
        return result;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(TestMember obj)
    {
        int hc = obj.MemberInfo.Name.GetHashCode();
        Debug.Log("Hash code: " + hc);
        return hc;
    }
}
```

All I got when executing is:

```
Hash code: 120
Hash code: 120
Hash code: 121
Comparing `x` with `x` Result: True
Hash code: 120
Hash code: 120
Hash code: 120
Comparing `x` with `x` Result: True
Hash code: 121
Comparing `y` with `y` Result: True
Hash code: 97
Hash code: 97
Hash code: 98
Hash code: 98
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that it's just a matter of `MemberInfo.Equals` not working as you expect. That's easy to test:

```
var m1 = get("x");
var m2 = get("x");
Console.WriteLine(m1.Equals(m2));
```

If that prints False, then that's the issue, and you should add your own caching.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You are correct, it printed out false. However a couple of things: 1- It worked perfectly in .NET but not in Mono, why? 2- Instead of `m1.Equals(m2)` I wrote `m1.MemberInfo.Equals(m2.MemberInfo)` and it printed true! - I guess `m1.Equals` is resolving to `Object.Equals` in this case?

Comment: I also tried using `MemberInfo.Name` instead of just `MemberInfo` in the `IEqualityComparer` `Equals` and `GetHashCode`. Still nothing from the intersection.

Comment: @vexe: I suspect .NET uses caching to return references to the same MemberInfo object each time. Given *my* code, `m1.MemberInfo` shouldn't compile. (I'm not using your `TestMember class.)

Comment: Yes but, what about `MemberInfo.Name`? I used that in the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` and still the same... Shouldn't it be the same name?

Comment: @vexe: Yes, that should work. Please show a short but complete example of that not working.

Comment: @vexe: In that case, I strongly advise you to add logging in the comparer - check when it's getting called and with what. Basically, try to reduce the number of places that could be broken. It may well be a Mono issue, but if you can pinpoint exactly where, that would help. In particular, I'd get rid of the `IntersectAll` call - you should be able to demonstrate this just using one call to `IntersectWith`.

Comment: "Add logging in the comparer" - Not sure where you mean. You mean inside `Equals` and `GetHashCode`?

Comment: Please see edit. Added some logs. I'm not sure if I logged interesting information, nor am I sure of what to make out of the resulting logs :s

Comment: @vexe: You'd need to add GetHashCode logging too. I'm afraid Stack Overflow doesn't work well for this sort of interactive debugging... I think I'm best stopping at this point.

Comment: Added it... and apologies.